# How to get rid of "offline mode" message bow in IE 8?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, winapi, internet-explorer-8

I would like to **COMPLETELY** get rid of the "Work Offline" message box.

[image]

To give some context, this message box appears on a machine running a **local** webapp.
The access to the network is clearly unstable so a momentary lack should never be blocking : it only delays some background notifications. The web pages only require local resources to be displayed. The urls look like `http://localhost:4444/*myApp*/...`

The machine runs on XP pro and the browser is IE8.

I have tried the following solutions without success:

1. Unchecking by hand the menu option *File/Work Offline* is not enough.
2. Setting the registry entries `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WebCheck\LoadSens` and `LoadLCE` to *`auto`*, then *`no`* then *`yes`*
3. I have tried to programatically force the online mode by calling this method up to every 200ms

   ```
   [DllImport("wininet.dll")]
   private extern static bool InternetSetOption(int hInternet,
   int dwOption, ref INTERNET_CONNECTED_INFO lpBuffer, int dwBufferLength);

   [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
   struct INTERNET_CONNECTED_INFO
   {
       public int dwConnectedState;
       public int dwFlags;
   };
   private static readonly int INTERNET_STATE_DISCONNECTED = 16;
   private static readonly int INTERNET_STATE_CONNECTED = 1;
   private static readonly int ISO_FORCE_DISCONNECTED = 1;
   private static readonly int INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECTED_STATE = 50;

   private static Timer aTimer;
   private bool offlineSelected = false;

   public void SetIEOfflineMode(bool offline)
   {
       INTERNET_CONNECTED_INFO ici = new INTERNET_CONNECTED_INFO();

       if (offline)
       {
           ici.dwConnectedState = INTERNET_STATE_DISCONNECTED;
           ici.dwFlags = ISO_FORCE_DISCONNECTED;
           Debug.WriteLine("switching to offline mode");
       }
       else
       {
           ici.dwConnectedState = INTERNET_STATE_CONNECTED;
           Debug.WriteLine("switching to online mode");
       }

       InternetSetOption(0, INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECTED_STATE, ref ici, Marshal.SizeOf(ici));
   }
   ```

The last attempt almost works. The *'Work Offline'* never remains checked but sometimes (quite randomly indeed) the evil message box appears. The problem is that despite it never remains blocking (the working mode switches to *online* so the pages work properly) it disturbs the end user.

One remark: we cannot chenge the architecture (local web application) even though it may look a bit weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since anyone else couldn't help me, I finally found a solution. A bit dirty but working one.
The trick is simulate a click on the *"Try Again"* button. I did this by using `user32.dll` functions. Here are the steps:

1. You first find the parent window's handle by using the `FindWindow` function.
2. You find the button with `FindWindowEx`from its caption and its parent window's handle.
3. You finally send the click with `SendMessage`

Here is the declaration of the required functions

```
// For Windows Mobile, replace user32.dll with coredll.dll
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className, string windowTitle);

const uint WM_CLOSE = 0x10;
const uint BM_CLICK = 0x00F5;
```

And here is the method using them

```
private bool ClickButton(String window, String button)
{
    IntPtr errorPopUp;
    IntPtr buttonHandle;

    bool found = false;
    try
    {
        errorPopUp = FindWindow(null, window.Trim());
        found = errorPopUp.ToInt32() != 0;
        if (found)
        {
            found = false;
            buttonHandle = FindWindowEx(errorPopUp, IntPtr.Zero, null, button.Trim());
            found = buttonHandle.ToInt32() != 0;
            if (found)
            {
                SendMessage(buttonHandle, BM_CLICK, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
                Trace.WriteLine("Clicked \"" + button + "\" on window named \"" + window + "\"");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Found Window \"" + window + "\" but not its button \"" + button + "\"");
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.TraceError(ex.ToString());
    }
    return found;
}
```

`window` is the title (=*"Work Offline"*) of the window and `button` the caption of the button (=*"&Try Again"*).

**Note** : Do not forget the ampersand (*"&"*) preceding subtitled letters.